# How are "the average number of comparisons required by general sorting algorithms" calculated?

Tags: sorting

Just started studying papers about sorting algorithms, which I found one states that:

> It is well known that general sorting algorithms need in the worst case at least
>
> [image]
>
> comparisons and, on an average, at least
>
> [image]
>
> comparisons.

For the worst case analysis, the result is calculated by (according to my understanding):

For a input of n different entries, there are at most n! permutations, which only 1 of them is the sorted list. If an algorithm always fisinhs after f(n) steps (comparisons), it can at most distinguish 2^f(n) different permutations, due to the fact there are only 2 result of each comparison, eliminating half of the possibilities.

Therefore, the algorithm must at least yield `2^f(n) >= n!`, or `f(n) >= log n!`.

Since the number of comparisons is definitely a whole number, we can assume the lower bound of it at worst case as `ceil(log n!)`
, then use the Strling’s Formula to simplify:

[image]

Thus getting the claimed formula in the paragraph. However, I have zero idea for even how to start understanding the average case formula. Any hint on what should I look up for?

What I'd found that's the most related to this are these:

[Minimum number of comparisons needed to use merge sort algorithm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10249208/minimum-number-of-comparisons-needed-to-use-merge-sort-algorithm)

[Number of Comparisons in Merge-Sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12346054/number-of-comparisons-in-merge-sort/12346159#12346159)

Though it doesn't quite help on calculating the general formula, at least for me.

Comment: "average case formula" only makes sense for a specific algorithm. The "worst-case formula" you've found in your book is a hard limit *for all comparison-based sorting algorithms*.

Comment: Also, using an approximation with "+ Theta(log(n))" when trying to calculate an *exact* lower bound makes no sense. The Theta() notation hides an unspecified factor. You need a more explicit approximation to get the result.